# Is it possible to use hadoop as a database/backend for a ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, hadoop, backend

Can somebody tell me that can we use hadoop as a backend for my ruby on rails application since my app consists of huge amount of data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you couldn't use Hadoop as your backend to ruby on rails application as Hadoop is a high-latency system, and is not build for random-access of data. I would recommend you take a look at [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org), which are scalable yet allows random access of data (records).